# Basic java recursion error

Tags: java

```
public static long fibby(long n){
        if (n == 0){
            return 1;
        }   
        return (fibby(n/4))+(fibby(3*n/4)); 
    }    
public static void sparsetablegen(int start, int end){

          long fibbyOut = fibby(start);
          long lastFibbyOutput = fibbyOut;
          System.out.println(start+" "+fibbyOut);

          if(start != end){
              sparsetablegen(start+1, end);
              if (lastFibbyOutput == fibbyOut){
                  return;
              }
          }
    }
```

Disclaimer: This is an assignment for my java project and I've tried multiple approaches and can not figure out a working solution. I will post what my understanding of the code is and what's not working properly.

What my table is supposed to do is take in values, starting from "int start" and finishing at int "end", those values will then be solved by my "fibby" function. Then it should print the values of "start" and fibbyOut side by side until it hits the "end".
What I'm supposed to do is skip over any duplicate values of fibbyOut
    So for example I might see:
    1 -> 2
    2 -> 3
    3 -> 4
    4 -> 6 
    5 -> 6
    6 -> 8

And so then I would want to skip over the start value 5, since fibbyOut for 4 is 6 and that's a duplicate value.
    So instead I should see
    1-> 2
    2-> 3
    3-> 4
    4-> 6
    6-> 8

I know it's a very basic problem, but I just can't seem to figure how to remove the duplicate values of fibbyOut. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can not see any recursive code here.

Comment: I see no recursion here - based on your question, perhaps you meant duplication (in the sense that the data values may recur). Recursion has a very *different* meaning for codecutters.

Comment: as a side note this --> `if (lastFibbyOutput == fibbyOut)` is always true.

Comment: You should include the original problem statement so that we know what you are supposed to be solving.

Comment: I think I'd also ask for the original problem statement.  It's commendable to try to restate it in your own words, but your description has me very confused.  I think you're trying to say that you should skip (not recalculate) values in your table of Fibonacci numbers, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: I added the missing code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASSIVE EDIT: After coming to the understanding of what the problem truly was, I typed out this:

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Long> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
        table(0, 8, outputs);
    }

    public static void table(int start, int end, List<Long> outputs) {
        outputs.add(fibby(start));
        long lastFibbyOutput = outputs.get(outputs.size() - 1);

        for(int i = outputs.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(outputs.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println(start + " " + lastFibbyOutput); //Always print the first time because it will be a unique value.
                break;
            } else if(outputs.get(i) == lastFibbyOutput) {
                //One of the values matches a previous one, so we break
                break;
            }

            //We're at the end without breaking, so we print.
            if(i == 0) System.out.println(start + " " + lastFibbyOutput);
        }

        if(start == end) {
            return;
        }

        start++;
        table(start, end, outputs);
    }

    public static long fibby(long n) {
        if(n == 0) return 1;

        return (fibby(n/4) + fibby(3 * n / 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my fibby function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, that complicates things a bit. :) I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Also, what does sparsetablegen do?

Comment: Does that solve your problem? I used an ArrayList (my friggin' favorite part of Java--it solves so many problems), which wasn't a part of your original design, but it gets the job done for dynamic storage of outputs. I tested the output, and I saw that five and seven were properly omitted.

Comment: Yeah that's great. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: No problem! It was a unique problem that was fun to tackle! :D